# Which attribute do you use to store passwords in Keychain (using iOS)?

Tags: ios, security, swift, keychain

(I'm using Swift.)

I have the following `Dictionary` to pass to `SecItemAdd()`.

`var attributes = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassInternetPassword,
  kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly,
  kSecAttrDescription: "Alexander's Application Account Password",
  kSecAttrAccount: self.usernameField.text, /* This is an outlet to a UITextField */
  kSecAttrServer: "http://www.hausofalexander.tk/", /* This is my servers' domain */
  kSecAttrAuthenticationType: kSecAttrAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic,
  kSecValueData: self.passwordField.text]; /* This is also and outlet to a UITextField */`

Then I call `SecItemAdd(attributes as CFDictionaryRef, nil)`

I'm receiving `errSecParam` (which is error `-50`) because I'm passing an invalid parameter (`attributes` in this case) to `SecItemAdd()`. I'm assuming this is because I've a pair for `kSecValueData` in my `attributes` variable which isn't applicable to `kSecClassInternetPassword` for iOS according to the reference: [Make sure you scroll down a bit to the `kSecClassInternetPassword` item to see the applicable attributes for a `kSecClass` of this type.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Item_Class_Value_Constants)

However, I'm completely able to use `kSecValueData` as an attribute and set a value for it with Cocoa (as in Mac development). I've made a Mac application to test this then looked for the item with Keychain Access to find that it was indeed there. However, this was using a `kSecClass` of `kSecClassGenericPassword` (I don't know if this is relevant, but this test application I'd written in Objective-C). At this point I'd decided to check which attributes are available if I were to use `kSecClassGenericPassword` in my iOS application. Sadly, `kSecValueData` isn't available for that `kSecClass`, either.

So where in the world do I set the password if `kSecValueData` isn't an applicable attribute to `kSecClassGenericPassword`, `kSecClassInternetPassword`, nor any other `kSecClass` items?

I've noticed that I'm allowed to use `kSecAttrGeneric` with these `kSecClass` items (namely `kSecClassGenericPassword` and `kSecClassInternetPassword`) and it takes a value of `CFDataRef`. I'm assuming that means I'm expected to pass `NSData` (as `CFDataRef`) to this attribute, but what do I pass as the `NSData`? Should that be a `Dictionary`? Should that be an `NSASCIIStringEncoding` value of the password `String`? Does this mean I can make any `kSecAttr*` value myself somehow?

Thanks for reading. If I've confused you, do tell and I'll happily explain in further detail.

Comment: maybe this will help - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922081/which-key-should-i-use-to-store-the-password-in-ios-keychain?rq=1

Comment: I've been attempting to make this work for a bit, but `kSecValueData` simply isn't applicable. I've tried `var attributes = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,kSecAttrAcces...blah blah...trAccount: self.usernameField.text,kSecValueData as String: self.passwordField.text.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)];`. After logging all of the Keychain items for the application I've found that `kSecValueData` is not being added as an attribute. Would it be bad practice to use `kSecGenericItem` instead? That's working well here.

Comment: I have had issues getting these to work in the simulator but it ends up working on a device. Apple's example project helped me figure out the issues.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/accessing_keychain_items_with_face_id_or_touch_id